# Run Swing JNLP with JavaFX console

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jnlp

I want to run my `Swing` application from `JNLP` file and show the pretty `JavaFX` console. Is it possible? What params should I add to `JNLP configuration`?

**UPD:** standard `AWT/Swing` console is shown as well. I want to show the `JavaFX` one.

**UPD2:** I have some components from JavaFX in my app, but main frame is instance of `JFrame`, so the code `<jfx:javafx-desc main-class="my.MainClass" name="MainClass"/>` won't work.

Comment: *"What params should I add to JNLP configuration?"*  It is not possible to pop the Java Console just by params in the JNLP, so it will not be possible to pop this Java-FX console from the same.

Comment: Ok. So, how can I do that?

Comment: From a copy/paste comment:  Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: What is your comment about? I know how to set Java Console visible. My question is about how to replace standard Java `AWT/Swing` console with new `JavaFX` one.

Comment: Do you see the problem with asking someone to describe 'that'?  More words is better than less.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. Updated